# Should I add headers as INTERFACE target sources, or just set an INTERFACE target include directory?

Tags: cmake, build, libraries, build-dependencies

In a repository using CMake, I have a library `foo` which gets compiled from `foo.c`. There is also a file `foo.h` which, for the sake of discussion, is only necessary when compiling code against `foo`. Both the compiled library and `foo.h` get installed.

Now, how should I "announce" `foo.h` to dependent targets? Should I write:

```
target_sources(foo INTERFACE "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>/foo.h")
```

, or perhaps:

```
target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GENERATED_INCLUDE_DIR}>")
```

or - maybe both?

Comment: If you really want to install to `/usr/include` the second one is fine and the first one would create confusion at best (non-editable header occuring among "out of thin air" among the source files of linking targets for IDEs that do show you the sources you add to targets in cmake). Otherwise assuming you provide the user with a cmake configuration script generated by cmake the second snippet should be adjusted to include the include directory at the time of installation (restricted to the install interface via generator expression of course).

Comment: @fabian: Where did I imply I want to isntall anything into `/usr/include`? It's whatever install location the user has chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the latter. `foo.h` is not one of the first-party sources of the linkee, which is what `(INTERFACE_)SOURCES` is supposed to model. Then the target `foo` in order to be used requires that the linkee can find its headers; those belong in `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` (which `target_include_directories` sets).

Comment: I mis-copy-pasted the PRIVATE. Would you mind editing your answer accordingly?

Comment: But aren't you essentially saying that `.h` files aren't really sources? In which case I shouldn't list them as sources to begin with?

Comment: @einpoklum - no, I'm not. The `(INTERFACE_)SOURCES` properties are for _first-party_ sources. You don't think of the Boost headers as being part of the target that happens to use them. They belong to the Boost library. Same deal here with `foo.h`, which belongs to `foo`. Setting headers has no effect on the actual build in CMake, but it does associate files with targets in the generated IDE project files, e.g. Visual Studio. You wouldn't want `foo.h` associated with a linkee `bar`. You'd want it associated with `foo`.